# Is it possible to remove the border between the segments but leave the border around the pie chart in react-chartjs-2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am using react-chartjs-2 pie chart and I'd like to remove the lines(borders) between slices BUT I want to show the border around the chart. Could someone tell me the way to do this ? Thanks in advance!

my code is like that now:

```
import {Pie} from 'react-chartjs-2';
class App extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div className='pieChartPositioner'>
            <Pie              
              height={36}
              width={36}
              data={{
                 datasets: [{
                     data: [20 , 80],
                     backgroundColor: ['red', 'green'],
                     borderColor: 'black',
                     borderWidth: 2,
                  }],
               }
             }/>
         </div>  
      )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `borderWidth` as `0` in the pie's `arc` configuration which by default is set to `2`.

> The arc configuration can be used in polar area, doughnut and pie
>   charts and is set under the `elements` key.

You can change it by either:

**1. Setting the global `arc` options**

`Chart.defaults.global.elements.arc.borderWidth = 0;`

**2. Or through the `options` object that you passed to the chart**

```js
var options = {
  elements: {
    arc: {
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  }
};
```

See [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html#arc-configuration) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this because marked answer didn't help me, I guess it was changed in meanwhile.

You need to set `borderWidth` inside datasets that you are passing to `data` prop.

Example:

```
const data = {
        datasets: [{
          borderWidth:0,
          data: [9, 1],
          backgroundColor: ['#ffffff', '#000000'],
        }],
    };
    
    return (
      <Pie data={data} />
    )
```